# Generate time as expression of 1/1000ths of the day

Tags: shell, date

Completely new to bash and having trouble working out how to make the arithmetic work. I think this should be easy, it's just.. argh.

I want to express the time of day in terms of 1/1000ths (ie, midday = 500, etc.)

I figured the script would need to find the number of seconds elapsed so far and then divide that number by 86.4, then return the resulting DDD

Any help? thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

First, here's how to show the number of hours, minutes and seconds elapsed since the beginning of the day:

```
date +%H:%M:%S
```

Since the display format can be customized, output an arithmetic expression that calculates the total number of seconds since midnight, and [place that](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) in a shell [arithmetic expression](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) construct.

```
s=$(($(date +"%H*3600+%M*60+%S")))
```

This returns a number of fractions of 1/86400th of a day. To get 1/1000ths, perform a little more arithmetic:

```
t=$(($s * 1000 / 86400))
```

which can be reduced to

```
t=$(($s * 5 / 432))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to do in my head. 


So, I've gotten as far as: 


    `#!/bin/bash` 
    `clear` 
    `s=$(($(date +"%H * 3600 + %M * 60 + %S")))` 
    `t=$(($s * 5 / 432))` 


...but, having just starting trying to learn about bash this morning, I'm not sure where to go from here to output a number. DO I need some kind of echo command?
I'm using this script with text expander and so far what I've got isn't producing anything viable...

Comment: `echo $t` after the calulations doesn't give you the correct ouput?

Comment: @Jack Anders: using `echo "$varname"` works, as does `printf "%d" "$varname"` (use %d,%s, etc as need be)... 'printf' requires a bit more typing, but is much more flexible, and avoids an occasional quirk of 'echo' in which it cannot differentiate between an option (eg: `-n` or `-e` and what it is supposed to 'echo'; when the first *word* of text to be echoed is the same as the option.  (many utilities allow you to use `--` to indicate *end-of-options*. However 'echo' does not have this '--' option.

Comment: Okay! wow. Thanks everyone for your help, I've put together a script that creates the timestamps I need:


    #!/bin/bash
    clear
    s=$(($(date +"%H*3600+%M*60+%S")))
    t=$(($s * 5 / 432))
    d=$(date +%j)
    y=$(date +%Y)
    printf "$y\`$d\`$t" "$y" "$d" "$t"'


But when the time is rendered, I need it to always display in three digits (ie, oo1, 098...), even if the number is less than 100.

Any suggestion about how I could accomplish that?